# how to lookup value for multiple value in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, fix-protocol

I have below `json` file in linux, I want to have a lookup for the tag from a file
p.s. i **don't** have `jq` installed and somehow no permission to install it.

```
{
    "time":"06/11 09:34:25.868969",
    "8":"FIX.4.2",
    "9":"347",
    "35":"D",
    "49":"ABC"
}
```

```
8 eight
9 nine
35 thirty_five
```

will return something like below, if no mapping found just print the original value

output:

```
{
    "time":"06/11 09:34:25.868969",
    "eight":"FIX.4.2",
    "nine":"347",
    "thirty_five":"D",
    "49":"ABC"
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can run the docker version of `jq` https://hub.docker.com/r/stedolan/jq or work out how to install it from here... https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Installation#zero-install

Answer (score 1):

Expect your **value_file** only has two columns, try this script:

```
js_file='json_file'
cp "$js_file" "$js_file"`date +%y%m%d%H%M%S`
val_file='value_file'
while IFS= read -r line; do
    line_arr=($line)
    sed -i 's/"'"${line_arr[0]}"'":"/"'"${line_arr[-1]}"'":"/' "$js_file"
done < "$val_file"
```

The `cp` command will backup the original file for rollback, you could remove that if you don't need.

`sed` will replace the value run likes this:
`sed -i 's/"35":"/"thirty_five":"/' json_file`